# JQuery .mouseover and .mouseout change font color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am newbie to JQuery and I try to make some basic tricks with it. So basicly, I have simple navigation made of unordered list, and I want to change font color on currently mouseover-ed list item with JQuery, but I have problem because my JQuery script is changing font color of all list items, and I want to change font color of ONLY currently mouseover-ed list item, not all. I tried to get currently mouseover-ed list item, but I don't know how to implement it so that my JQuery change only that list item. Here are pictures:

What I currently have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhUrs.jpg
What I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rTUV.jpg

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('.nav1 ul li').mouseover(
                function () {
                    var index = $( ".nav1 ul li" ).index(this);
                    $('.nav1 ul li a').css({"color":"white"});
                }
            );
            $('.nav1 ul li').mouseout(
                function () {
                    var index = $( ".nav1 ul li" ).index(this);
                    $('.nav1 ul li a').css({"color":"#6291d8"});
                }
            );
        }
);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="nav1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">THERAPIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BOOKING</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$('.nav1 ul li a').css({"color":"white"});
```

and:

```
$('.nav1 ul li a').css({"color":"#6291d8"});
```

use:

```
$(this).css({"color":"white"});
$(this).css({"color":"#6291d8"});
```

if you wan to apply css on achor tag:

```
$(this).find("a").css({"color":"white"});
$(this).find("a").css({"color":"#6291d8"});
```

By using `$('.nav1 ul li a')` you are changing all anchor tags css but but by using `$(this)` will change the current clicked element css.

Comment: Note that `this` will refer to the `li` element, not the `a` within it. If there are CSS classes set on the `a` of higher precedence, this may not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for JS here. You can use the CSS `:hover` psuedo class:

```
.nav1 ul li a { 
    color: #6291d8;
}
.nav1 ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hhgxm/)

Comment: this is the best as this simply can be achieved via css only, why bother js.

Answer (score 1):

Why `JQuery`?

use `a:hover` in `css` it is pretty cleaner.

Like:

```
.nav1 ul li a { 
    color: #6291d8;
}
.nav1 ul li a:hover{
color:white;
}
```

For all other links you can again use `a` and `a:hover` also **`a:active`** will give you additional functionality.

Comment: Looks like the OP is trying to learn jQuery (_"I am newbie to JQuery and I try to make some basic tricks with it."_)

Comment: @j08691 But still OP should use right tool for right task. Using JQuery for such an easy task will cost heavy to browser. anyway after all its OP's choice :)..

Comment: In principle I agree with you. Normally CSS would be the best route.

Comment: I know that I can use CSS for this, but as I wrote above, I am trying to learn JQuery, so I want to make this working with Jquery.

Comment: It's Okay @MahirDuraković. It is always nice to learn something. If you need any help again we are here :).

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a special word in JavaScript that refers to the element that triggers an event. In jQuery you can use `$(this)`. So you can replaceyour code with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav1 ul li a').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "white");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#6291d8");
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6N245/)**

Notice that I also changed the selector to `'.nav1 ul li a'`. The anchors have their own default styling, so to override that you should target them, and not the parent list item. I also replaced your `mouseover` and `mouseout` with the `hover` method as it saves a few characters. Finally, I used the more basic single property version of `.css()` which also saves a few characters.